# Why is one method slower than the other one

Tags: c

I have these two variants of my code which one of them runs significantly slower then the other one, although I think it should not do it. Could somebody please explain me what takes it so long to run while doing it like this?
The code is a basic floodfill algorithm, the pos variable is declared previously as **unsigned long**
Thank you

This piece of code runs much slower than the second one.

```
void
flood(byte * array, unsigned long x, unsigned long y, byte value)
{
    node_t *head = NULL;

    queue(&head, x, y);
    while (head != NULL) {
        unsigned long *ret = dequeue(&head);

        pos = ret[0] + ret[1] * pgmWidth;
        if (pos >= 0 && pos < pgmSize && ret[1] < pgmHeight &&
            array[pos] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos] = value;

            queue(&head, ret[0] + 1, ret[1]);
            queue(&head, ret[0], ret[1] + 1);
            queue(&head, ret[0], ret[1] - 1);
            queue(&head, ret[0] - 1, ret[1]);
        }
        free(ret);
    }
}
```

This piece runs much faster although there is more conditions then in the first one

```
void
flood(byte * array, unsigned long x, unsigned long y, byte value)
{
    node_t *head = NULL;

    queue(&head, x, y);
    while (head != NULL) {
        unsigned long *ret = dequeue(&head);

        pos = ret[0] + ret[1] * pgmWidth;
        if (ret[0] >= 0 && ret[0] < pgmWidth && ret[1] >= 0 &&
            ret[1] < pgmHeight && array[pos] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos] = value;

            queue(&head, ret[0] + 1, ret[1]);
            queue(&head, ret[0], ret[1] + 1);
            queue(&head, ret[0], ret[1] - 1);
            queue(&head, ret[0] - 1, ret[1]);
        }
        free(ret);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there are more conditions, maybe the conditions are met less often, so fewer things get queued.

Comment: Did you compile both with optimization on? What are the actual times? Can you put this in a [mcve] that demonstrates the difference?

Comment: There aren't more conditions. Both loops have 4 conditions, they're just a little different.

Comment: Both are run in the same conditions, times are roughly 4 and 7 seconds. It would be hard to do a minimal reproducible example since there is a lot of code behind. 

It is highly possible though, that splitting conditions might speed up the program. I was wondering if comparing long variables doesn't take more time than computing with integers, but the results were approximately the same

Comment: Are you compiling a release build with optimizations on?

Comment: The conditions are not equivalent and the first algorithm is wrong. For instance, it allows `ret[0] < 0`.

Comment: My first guess is that the two `if`s are not branching under the same conditions. I would put some logging in `queue()` that tracks every time it gets called, and with what arguments. I'd bet a nickel that you'll get different results.,

Comment: The `if` statements have the _same_ number of terms. But, one appears to be more restrictive (range wise) than the other. Are you getting the same number of `queue` calls for each example? Could you add counters to count number of iterations and number of queue operations (e.g. number of times the `if` is true) to verify that they are doing an equal amount of work? My guess is that example #2 is _more_ restrictive (rejects more input) than example #1

Comment: _Side note:_ Also, you are doing `free(ret);` but you have `unsigned long *ret`. The `free` implies a `malloc` somewhere and the only thing that makes sense [to me] is a linked list of some sort. So, I'd expect something like: `typedef struct node { struct node *next; unsigned long val[2]; } node_t;` and `node_t *ret = dequeue(&head);` So, what am I missing?

Comment: @CraigEstey: the array `val` must be at the beginning of the structure for `free(ret);` to actually free the node: `typedef struct node { unsigned long val[2]; struct node *next; } node_t;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a significant difference between the 2 functions: the second piece of code stops the flood at the left and right edges of the 2D array whereas the first does not.

The set of pixels that are explored is different: for example imagine the array is filled with `UCHAR_MAX` values except for a vertical line running from top to bottom. The first code will flood the array on both sides from any pixel not on the vertical line whereas the second will only flood half of the surface.

This possibly explains the difference in running times, depending on the actual contents of the array at the call.

Both approaches may make sense, but have different semantics:

- the first code floods the array as the surface of a cylinder with a one pixel misalignment along the junction.
- the second code floods the array as a flat rectangle, which seems more consistent.

There are ways to further improve the code:

- you should remove 2 redundant tests as the coordinates are unsigned, which are defined to have wrap around semantics,
- you should only queue pixels that are actually reached,
- you should change the pixel value before queueing the pixel coordinates to avoid queueing the same pixel multiple times.

```
void flood(byte *array, unsigned long x, unsigned long y, byte value)
{
    node_t *head = NULL;

    pos = x + y * pgmWidth;
    if (x < pgmWidth && y < pgmHeight && array[pos] == UCHAR_MAX) {
        array[pos] = value;
        queue(&head, x, y);
    }

    while (head != NULL) {
        unsigned long *ret = dequeue(&head);
        x = ret[0];
        y = ret[1];
        free(ret);

        pos = x + y * pgmWidth;
        
        if (x + 1 < pgmWidth && array[pos + 1] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos + 1] = value;
            queue(&head, x + 1, y);
        }
        if (y + 1 < pgmHeight && array[pos + pgmWidth] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos + pgmWidth] = value;
            queue(&head, x, y + 1);
        }
        if (y > 0 && array[pos - pgmWidth] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos - pgmWidth] = value;
            queue(&head, x, y - 1);
        }
        if (x > 0 && array[pos - 1] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos - 1] = value;
            queue(&head, x - 1, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, using global variables for `pos`, `pgmWidth` and `pgmHeight` makes the code slower. There is no real value in using a global variable for `pos` anyway. Try this alternative:

```
void flood(byte *array, unsigned long x, unsigned long y, byte value)
{
    node_t *head = NULL;
    unsigned long width = pgmWidth;
    unsigned long height = pgmHeight;
    unsigned long pos;

    p = x + y * width;
    if (x < width && y < height && array[pos] == UCHAR_MAX) {
        array[pos] = value;
        queue(&head, x, y);
    }

    while (head != NULL) {
        unsigned long *ret = dequeue(&head);
        x = ret[0];
        y = ret[1];
        free(ret);

        pos = x + y * width;
        
        if (x + 1 < width && array[pos + 1] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos + 1] = value;
            queue(&head, x + 1, y);
        }
        if (y + 1 < height && array[pos + width] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos + width] = value;
            queue(&head, x, y + 1);
        }
        if (y > 0 && array[pos - width] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos - width] = value;
            queue(&head, x, y - 1);
        }
        if (x > 0 && array[pos - 1] == UCHAR_MAX) {
            array[pos - 1] = value;
            queue(&head, x - 1, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW.... This makes me almost give up at programming. 0.12s execution time instead of those 4 secs or even 7 with my code. Thank you a lot, I am really amazed right now how crappy my code was and how it could be further improved without even knowing the rest of the code. You are a genius sir, thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the timing can be further improved by an order of magnitude in many cases by scanning horizontally and queueing segments instead of single pixels. Some pathological patterns can be very hard to fill efficiently.  Don't give up! It takes time and experience to come up with better algorithms.  Be curious, read a lot of code, try new things, study algorithms, complexity, but also practical cases.  Be passionate! If you like programming, the trip lasts a lifetime and you'll learn something new every day and enjoy it.